# How do you play really short notes on the acoustic guitar?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I was wondering how it is possible to play very short notes on the acoustic guitar. Lets say 1/32. If you pick the string it is vibrating for some time. 
So what are the options to make it short?

1. Tap the string after so it stops vibrating
2. Pick the string with less force
3. Do something else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several options - release the fretting finger, but only enough to stop the string vibrating - not off completely. Touch the string with another finger from the fretting hand. Touch the string with a finger or palm of the picking hand.Play the next note on the same string, so the original has to stop.After playing the note (with a pick), put the pick back touching the string.

Tapping the string is not going to work - it'll probably make a different sound. Picking gently will make a held note last less time, but not what you want.

Of course, a 1/32 note will vary in length as to the tempo of the song.